# Array of shortened integers

Tags: c#, memory, collections, compression

Just to avoid inventing hot-water, I am asking here...

I have an application with lots of arrays, and it is running out of memory.

So the thought is to compress the `List<int>` to something else, that would have same interface (`IList<T>` for example), but instead of `int` I could use shorter integers.

For example, if my value range is 0 - 100.000.000 I need only ln2(1000000) = 20 bits.  So instead of storing 32 bits, I can trim the excess and reduce memory requirements by 12/32 = 37.5%.

Do you know of an implementation of such array.  c++ and java would be also OK, since I could easily convert them to c#.

Additional requirements (since everyone is starting to getting me OUT of the idea):

- integers in the list ARE unique
- they have no special property so they aren't compressible in any other way then reducing the bit count
- if the value range is one million for example, lists would be from 2 to 1000 elements in size, but there will be plenty of them, so no BitSets
- new data container should behave like re-sizable array (regarding method O()-ness)

EDIT:

*Please don't tell me NOT to do it. The requirement for this is well thought-over, and it is the ONLY option that is left.*

**Also, 1M of value range and 20 bit for it is ONLY AN EXAMPLE.  I have cases with all different ranges and integer sizes.**

Also, I could have even shorter integers, for example 7 bit integers, then packing would be

```
00000001
11111122
22222333
33334444
444.....
```

for first 4 elements, packed into 5 bytes.

---

Almost done coding it - will be posted soon...

Comment: If your integers are that short then you want a `List<byte>` instead of a `List<int>`. In any case, this is the same idea as point #3 in my answer. You would need to do something like what the specialized `std::vector<bool>` does to pack bits together. There should be an implementation you can read somewhere.

Comment: Jon - I added "for example" two times, in case that you didn't notice.

Comment: Relax mate. I 'm *really* trying to help here, in case you didn't notice. ;-)

Comment: Help would be a link to a container implementation :)

Comment: Since the integers are unique (I think) you can drastically reduce the storage space by keeping track of the integers you've "seen" until you reach half of the maximum. Then just keep track of the integers you don't have.

Comment: @MrMusic I don't understand that, but you might be on to something...  Anyway, I'll always have lists of orders of magnitude smaller than the integer maximum value...  so for example 1000 elements will be some kind of practical upper limit in case that there are 1M value range

Comment: @DanielMošmondor In that case I don't think my solution will work. I was thinking of having lists containg at most, say, 1000 elements in the range of 0-999. In that case once you have 501 items in the list you can start to store the items you don't have. So a list "containing" every integer in the range [0, 999] except 97 and 111 would only need to store 97 and 111. So yeah I don't think this works in your case.

Comment: Use pointers and [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]

Answer (score 3):

Since you can only allocate memory in byte quantums, you are essentially asking if/how you can fit the integers in 3 bytes instead of 4 (but see #3 below). This is **not a good idea**.

1. Since there is no 3-byte sized integer type, you would need to use something else (e.g. an opaque 3-byte buffer) in its place. This would require that you wrap all access to the contents of the list in code that performs the conversion so that you can still put "ints" in and pull "ints" out.
2. Depending on both the architecture and the memory allocator, requesting 3-byte chunks might not affect the memory footprint of your program at all (it might simply litter your heap with unusable 1-byte "holes").
3. Reimplementing the list from scratch to work with an opaque byte array as its backing store would avoid the two previous issues (and it can also let you squeeze every last bit of memory instead of just whole bytes), but it's a tall order and quite prone to error.

You might want instead to try something like:

- Not keeping all this data in memory at the same time. At 4 bytes per int, you 'd need to reach hundreds of millions of integers before memory runs out. Why do you need all of them at the same time?
- Compressing the dataset by not storing duplicates if possible. There are bound to be a few of them if you are up to hundreds of millions.
- Changing your data structure so that it stores differences between successive values (deltas), if that is possible. This might be not very hard to achieve, **but** you can only realistically expect something at the ballpark of 50% improvement (which may not be enough) and it will totally destroy your ability to index into the list in constant time.

Comment: @DanielMošmondor: I know that you won't like to hear this, but you are simply heading into a wall here. There is *no* way to satisfy all these requirements apart from writing your own container and doing lots of bit-twiddling to get that 38% reduction. If this is going to get the rocket on the moon and allow you to move on, then sure go ahead. Otherwise you will have to relax some restrictions.

Comment: It will do something alike getting rocket on the moon.  And I know that there'll be bit twiddling, just wanted to SEE if anyone has done that before.  I'll have to code it anyway.

Comment: @DanielMošmondor: Look into `std::vector<bool>` or into a UTF-8 encoder/decoder. Both of these place bits belonging to different values on the same byte and get them back out.

Answer (score 1):

One option that will get your from 32 bits to 24bits is to create a custom struct that stores an integer inside of 3 bytes:

```
public struct Entry {
    byte b1; // low
    byte b2; // middle
    byte b3; // high

    public void Set(int x) {
        b1 = (byte)x;
        b2 = (byte)(x >> 8);
        b3 = (byte)(x >> 16);
    }

    public int Get() {
        return (b3 << 16) | (b2 << 8) | b1;
    }
}
```

You can then just create a `List<Entry>`.

```
var list = new List<Entry>();
var e = new Entry();
e.Set(12312);
list.Add(e);
Console.WriteLine(list[0].Get()); // outputs 12312
```

Comment: How do you know that the allocator will not waste a "whole" 4-byte chunk if you only ask for 3 bytes?

Comment: You don't know at all how the jitter will allocate space for this. Sometimes they can be really smart but other times wasteful. But that is really outside of the programmers control (unless you role your own asm :) ).

Comment: That's my point exactly: you don't know, and you will never be able to know because this is an implementation detail that noone is going to expose -- and it could change at any time. Apart from that, the jitter has nothing to do with this. It's all the domain of the heap allocator.

Comment: Yep. I was loosely using the term jitter just to be the back-end. But trying to answer the posters question I felt this would be the closest to what he wanted. While we cannot be sure this will use less memory there is definitely a possibility it might.

Comment: Even if this code works as advertised today (which I sincerely doubt), there is no guarantee that it will work the same way tomorrow, or today on another system (e.g. 32 bit vs. 64 bit), or in a Debug and a Release build. Caveat emptor.

Answer (score 1):

This reminds me of base64 and similar kinds of [binary-to-text encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/binary-to-text_encoding).
They take 8 bit bytes and do a bunch of bit-fiddling to pack them into 4-, 5-, or 6-bit printable characters.
This also reminds me of the Zork Standard Code for Information Interchange (ZSCII), which packs 3 letters into 2 bytes, where each letter occupies 5 bits.
It sounds like you want to taking a bunch of 10- or 20-bit integers and pack them into a buffer of 8-bit bytes.

The source code is available for many libraries that handle a packed array of single bits
([a](http://javasourcecode.org/html/open-source/jdk/jdk-6u23/sun/security/util/BitArray.java.html)
[b](http://webster.cs.ucr.edu/AoA/DOS/ch09/CH09-7.html#HEADING7-9)
[c](http://michael.dipperstein.com/bitlibs/#bitarray)
[d](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/JIBitArray.aspx)
[e](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/BitArray.aspx)).

Perhaps you could
(a) download that source code and modify the source (starting from some BitArray or other packed encoding), recompiling to create a new library that handles packing and unpacking 10- or 20-bit integers rather than single bits.
It may take less programming and testing time to
(b) write a library that, from the outside, appears to act just like (a), but internally it breaks up 20-bit integers into 20 separate bits, then stores them using an (unmodified) BitArray class.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**: Given that your integers are unique you could do the following: store unique integers until the number of integers you're storing is half the maximum number. Then switch to storing the integers you don't have. This will reduce the storage space by 50%.

Might be worth exploring other simplification techniques before trying to use 20-bit ints.

**How do you treat duplicate integers?** If have lots of duplicates you could reduce the storage size by storing the integers in a `Dictionary<int, int>` where keys are unique integers and values are corresponding counts. Note this assumes you don't care about the order of your integers.

**Are your integers all unique?** Perhaps you're storing lots of unique integers in the range 0 to 100 mil. In this case you could try storing the integers you don't have. Then when determining if you have an integer `i` just ask if it's not in your collection.

Comment: @DanielMošmondor I updated my answer. See the edit at the top where I propose a method for reducing the storage space by 50%.